# Animate complete fires immediately

Tags: jquery

In my below code, I would expect the `diag1` div to increment slowly - once after end of each animation. Instead, it immediately goes to 20 and animation lags behind. I thought the whole point of the function argument in `.animate` was to callback a function AFTER completion of the animation. Can someone spot my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TST</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
        <script>
            PLAY=true;
            END_TIME = 20;
            CURRENT_TIME = 1;

            function scrollManager() {
                if(PLAY==true && CURRENT_TIME < END_TIME) {
                    CURRENT_TIME++;
                    scrollLeft();
                }
            }

            function scrollLeft() {
                $('#diag1').html(CURRENT_TIME);
                $('#s6').animate(
                    {'padding-left': '-=5%'},
                    1000, 'linear', scrollManager());
            }

            $(function() {
                $('#play_button').click(function() {
                    PLAY = true;
                    scrollManager();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <div id="ui">
                <button id="play_button">Play</button>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tst1">
                        <div id="s6" style="padding-left:70%;width:5%;background-color:red;">
                            <div>TEST</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="diag1">Diagnostic 1: </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `()` on scrollManager. `()` is an operator to call function in JS.

```
$('#s6').animate({'padding-left': '-=5%'}, 1000, 'linear', scrollManager);
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the prompt and clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because inside of scrollLeft, and inside of the animate function call, the expected argument is a callback. However, you have given `undefined` as opposed to the callback.

```
$('#s6').animate(
 {'padding-left': '-=5%'},
 1000, 'linear', scrollManager()
);
```

Using `scrollManager()` there will use the *returned* value from that function call as the callback. Since there is no returned value, `undefined` is assigned to the callback value.

What did happen is that `scrollManager()` was called. Which in turn calls `scrollLeft` again (essentially a recursive call). This recursion occurs until `if(PLAY==true && CURRENT_TIME < END_TIME)` is false.

The callback value expects either a function handle, or an anonymous function to use, so you should instead use

```
$('#s6').animate(
 {'padding-left': '-=5%'},
 1000, 'linear', scrollManager
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Thorough explanation appreciated.